# Higher level Spells

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just want to know if anyone has found any higher level spells? For example is there a Bound Armor spell in Skyrim? If so who do I buy it from? I'm level 47 and I keep checking for a Bound armor spell or more advanced Restoration spells and I just can't seem to find any. I have Bound Sword, Bound Battle Axe, and Bound bow, but where are all the master spells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no bound armor spell, unfortunately. You can check the list of spells on [UESP Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Spells).

Answer (score 1):

Before higher-level spells are available to you, you need to become proficient in whichever field of magic they require. Also master level spells are only available once you finish the "final exam" quest for their particular field of magic. But if you learn every single spell in the game, you will find that there is no bound armor spell.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to bound armor spells in Skyrim are Flesh spells in Alteration.

You will probably want to talk to Tolfdir at the College, as he is the master Alteration trainer. There may be one or two other mages in Skyrim that sell adept level Alteration tomes, but only Tolfdir sells expert spells and he is the one to start you on the quest for master Alteration spells(one of which is the strongest flesh spell in the game).